# Getting the ActiveRecord_Relation that received the class method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Having:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  def self.to_csv
    # irrelevant
  end
end
```

Rails allow me to do:

```
Foo.all.to_csv
```

But how would I access the collection that received the method call inside `to_csv`? (`all` in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem counter intuitive but you can use `#all`

For example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_csv
    all.map(&:convert_to_csv)
  end
end
```

Not only this will work with `Foo.all.to_csv` but also with `Foo.where(...).to_csv`

If you look at the source of `#all` inside `ActiveRecord`:

```
def all
  if current_scope
    current_scope.clone
  else
    default_scoped
  end
end
```

This means if you have defined a scope with `where` or `limit` it will respect it. Or if you're grabbing all records it will just use `default_scoped`